# linux terminal curl: option -: is unknown error

Tags: linux, curl

I keep trying to run this code but i keep getting the error "curl: option -: is unknown" HERE IS THE CODE

```
#!/bin/bash
#crawl End Clothing for Product IDs
for i in $(eval echo {$1..$2})
do

rm -f end-cookie.jar
curl -c end-cookie.jar - L http://www.endclothing.com/checkout/cart/add/eunc/a,,/product/204726 -s -o /dev/null

url=`curl -b end-cookie.jar -w "%{url_effective}\n" - L -s -S -o /dev/null http://www.endclothing.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/a,,/product/$i`

echo $i - $url

done
```

and when i run that i get the error

```
akshayk17j@ubuntu:~$ /home/akshayk17j/Desktop/TheEnd.sh
curl: option -: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
curl: option -: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
{..} -
```

HOW DO I FIX THIS? I dont know much about linux.

also i recieved this code in picture format and had to type it up. it also said "Usage: ./TheEnd.sh 1 500000" but idk what that means. thanks for your help

Comment: What has this to do with php?

Comment: Ask for a better original so you can type it up more safely... . Also not a programming question.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you have a space between the hyphen and the capital L. Try removing that; i.e.

```
- L
```

Becomes

```
-L
```

Comment: I had a similar whitespace typo. So was a useful answer for me. Thanks.